# Getting Tokens Antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I just started learning Antlr. I have a two part question. I am a visual learner, and I can’t find anywhere how to do this.

I want to know how to get the tokens from the .token file and match it to the token class.

Example:

```
LETTERS : A
LETTERS : B
NUMBERS : 0
NUMBERS : 8
```

My next question is How do I separate the Unknown Tokens and invalid tokens to another list.

Like for example

Recognized Tokens:

```
LETTERS : A
LETTERS : B
NUMBERS : 0
NUMBERS : 8
```

Unrecognized Tokens:

```
(
$
@
```

Invalid Tokens:

```
 ?
 ?
 ?
```